# Receiving 403 (Forbidden) via Microsoft Chatbot Composer (1.4.1) that is tied to LUIS and QNA

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

We are trying to develop a new chatbot via Bot Composer, and when we try to run the bot via emulator, and interaction we do with the bot comes back with a '403 (Forbidden)' response.  We confirmed all keys and hostnames are correct. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you manually added a prediction resource to your luis app?

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the "LUIS endpoint key" blank and use only the "LUIS authoring key"

When using the "LUIS endpoint key" the requests go to the prediction resource but for that to work with the emulator you have to publish the LUIS applications and make the endpoints public, all of them (LUIS portal > foreach application > manage > settings > Make endpoints public -> ON)

You don't have that restriction with the authoring endpoint, but there's a limit on the requests rate. However that shouldn't be a problem for testing with the emulator.